# Publicity banner is SO BROKEN: hitbox is HUGE and it is invincible to damage!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I'm not sure whether this is a consequence of the new CSS or not. We have a very visible publicity banner - it is shifted over to the side, and extends infinitely to the right. Perhaps as a consequence of the stretch placing the "close" action off to the horizon, the banner is also impossible to kill.

Apparently, this applies to IE7. I was originally going to call this as IE8, but it turns out I was actually on Compatibility Mode, for some reason. No repro on IE8, no access to any other browser at the moment. XP as OS.

Below is a screenshot of this unbalanced foe.

[image: Image of publicity popup, which is extended and lacks a close]

Comment: I don't even see that box at all in Chrome

Comment: @Charles the box does not always appear for everyone for that question. I do see that box correctly for other questions in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the next build this box will have a `max-width`. It still looks wrong (the position isn't correct etc.), but at least the "close" link isn't riding away towards the sunset.

Making it appear precisely as in other browsers would require some bigger changes, which isn't worth doing just for IE7.

Comment: +1 for IE hate.

Comment: Note that according to [some statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp), IE 7 (and 6!) still account for more than 10% of web users.

Comment: @Wikwocket [IE 6 has about 2-3% on StackOverflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/), and we no longer officially support it. We guarantee that the sites will work with IE7, but not that everything will look pixel-perfect.

Comment: This is satisfactory to me. I loathe using IE7 and never intend to - I'll stick to Chrome and IE8. Nevertheless, at least taking out the immortality of the box is quite good enough, since the rest is just graphics errors which bunches of non-interfering ones already exist for IE7 anyway.